# Junit output for Jasmine 3.x

Tags: junit, jasmine

I'm trying to run tests in jasmine and have them output a junit file.  I've seen npm install -g jasmine-xml-reporter but that seems to only be for jasmine 2.x.  Is there a way to run tests in jasmine 3.x and have the junit output?

I'm using jasmine as the test runner itself.